# how to upload my project files to online svn host?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have an account on projectlocker (free svn host), and I don't know how to upload my project files to it.

I don't find any option for that in my dashboard.

I am using tortoiseSvn on my computer , so how to upload files and configure tortoiseSvn?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Before importing your files I suggest you setup the basic structure of your repository.
The typical structure looks like this:

```
|
+- trunk
+- branches
+- tags
```

You can prepare that structure using the repo-browser. To open the repo-browser right-click on the desktop and select `TortoiseSVN -> Repo-browser` from the context menu. Then type the repository URL as prompted.

The repo-browser presents an explorer like interface to the repository where you can right-click in the folder structure and use the *New folder* context menu option to create a folder.

Now for *importing the files* proper I see at least two methods.

**Method 1 - Selectively commit the files**

Right-click in the folder of your choice and select `Checkout...` from the context menu.

In the checkout dialog type the URL of the repository where your files will reside (e.g. *https://project.example.com/svn/project/trunk*) and the name of a new directory where you'll be working (i.e. *the working copy*).

Copy your files into the working copy.

When you are satisfied with the arrangement, right-click on the working copy *root* folder and select `Commit...` from the context menu.

Click the checkboxe beside each file that needs to be versioned.

Write a short commit message (eg. `First commit`) then click the `Commit` button.

**Method 2 - Import everything**

Right-click on the folder containing your files and select `Import...` from the context menu.

In the import dialog type the repository URL where these files shoud reside (e.g. *https://project.example.com/svn/project/trunk*) and write a short commit message such as `Initial import`.

Then right-click in the location of your choice select `Checkout...` from the context menu and type the URL of your project and the path for your working copy.

The working copy will be populated with your files. If everything looks right you can continue working from there.

Answer (score 5):

Simply create the local working copy (put in your repo url that they will provide), and then move your files into that directory, and add/commit them. Same as you would do with any SVN system.